# Show the SwitchUser Screen

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, customization, user-customization

I am working on an application to cutomize the switch user and logon screen of Windows 7.

My application is built as a wizard,a dn on the last step, I want the user to be able to view the Switch User screen by pressing a button, like he/she would do by Start menu:

[image]

Comment: I think [this](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/) is what you need.

Comment: @Bowen, write that as answer for me to mark it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from [**Shortcut to Switch User in Windows Vista**](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

class Program
{
  [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool WTSDisconnectSession(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, bool bWait);

  const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
  static readonly IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (!WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
         WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, false))
      throw new Win32Exception();
  }
}
```